# XLSXWriter and Excel "=FILTER()" Function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsxwriter

I'm successfully creating many Excel workbooks using XLSXWriter. Now I'm trying to place one of Excel's new (as of 2019) FILTER functions into a cell:

```
=FILTER(A19:B90,B19:B90=E19)
```

When I open the workbook, Excel gives me this error dialog:

[image]

The workbook opens, but a "0" is in the cell instead of the FILTER function.

But if I paste the exact same filter function into the same cell manually, it works!

All the other formulas I'm creating work as expected, and if I use XLSXWriter to place a generic function into the same cell where I want the filter to go, e.g. `=100 *5`, it also works.

Does XLSXWriter have a bug when it comes to using `=FILTER()` functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little bit of an odd one. From the XlsxWriter docs on [Formulas added in Excel 2010 and later](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formulas-added-in-excel-2010-and-later):

> Excel 2010 and later added functions which weren’t defined in the original file specification. These functions are referred to by Microsoft as future functions. Examples of these functions are `ACOT`, `CHISQ.DIST.RT` , `CONFIDENCE.NORM`, `STDEV.P`, `STDEV.S` and `WORKDAY.INTL`.

> When written using `write_formula()` these functions need to be fully qualified with a `_xlfn.` (or other) prefix as they are shown the list below. For example:

> 

worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=_xlfn.STDEV.S(B1:B10)')

> ```
> They will appear without the prefix in Excel
> ```

However, this formula has a `_xlfn._xlws.` prefix and is also an array formula so you would have to do this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write_array_formula('C1:D72', 
                              '=_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(A19:B90,B19:B90=E19)')

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

One difference between the XlsxWriter output and Excel's is that this shows the array formula as `{FILTER(...)}`, with braces that are typical of array formulas, but Excel doesn't. However, I think the formula works as intended. You can try it in a more complex example to verify.

**Update**:

The reason that this formula is different from other Excel formulas is because it is one of the new [Dynamic array functions](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/07/08/excel-dynamic-arrays-functions-formulas/#dynamic-array-functions) added in Excel 365.

Comment: I had the same problem and I found this answer after inspect the internal XML generated by Excel.