# XLSXWriter and Excel “=SORT()” Function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsxwriter

I learned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838976/xlsxwriter-and-excel-filter-function) about using XLSXWriter to add a `=FILTER()` function to a workbook.

Now I'm trying to add a `=SORT()` function. So far I have tried this:

```
worksheet.write_array_formula('H2', '=_xlfn._xlws.SORT(A2:F16, 6, -1)')
```

...but `SORT` doesn't appear to be an array formula. I have also tried this:

```
worksheet.write_formula('H2', '=_xlfn.SORT(A2:F16, 6, -1)')

worksheet.write_formula('H2', '=_xlfn._xlws.SORT(A2:F16, 6, -1)')
```

The formula appears in the worksheet, but instead of being:

```
=SORT(A2:F16, 6, -1)
```

...it appears as:

```
=@SORT(A2:F16, 6, -1)
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to the other answer that you linked to and your first attempt is almost correct. I think you just need to specify a range that the range formula applies to like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write_array_formula('H2:M16', 
                              '=_xlfn._xlws.SORT(A2:F16, 6, -1)')

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]